# ie7 position absolute bug

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, jquery-animate, css-position

Consider the following code which works great in all modern browsers.

CSS:

```
    .container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 150px;
        border: solid 1px #CCC;
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .toc {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 1px;
    }

    .sections {
        width: 800px;
    }

    .item {
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        height: 150px;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
```

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="toc">
    <a data-rank="0" href="javascript:;">1</a><a data-rank="1" href="javascript:;">2</a>
</div>
<div class="sections">
    <div class="item" data-rank="0">
        <h1>1: Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-rank="1">
        <h2>2: Hello World</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on("click",function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        var s = $target.attr('data-rank');

        $('.sections').animate({ marginLeft : + -(s * 400) + "px"}, 1200);
    });
});
```

Problem: In IE7 the "toc-div" is animated as well as the "sections-div". Change it's position to relative instead of absolute and it will work but then I am unable to place it where I want it.

I'd much appreciate a solution!

Comment: ie7 had some issues in regards to the absolute positioning of elements with in their parent container sometimes at least in terms of z-index and such.  You might want to try setting that container element to position absolute as well even though that may cause you more work.

Comment: Can you post a sample demo or something like that in jsfiddle?

Comment: nvm I figured it out, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding the following to .toc css

```
left: 0;
```

I was testing on my VM IE7 and it seems to work. Also, with the code provided I was not able to click the links in FF 11 I think, I had to add z-index.

Comment: Thank you, had no idea it would be that simple!

Comment: yea once I had a typo which took awhile to find

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be adding:

```
zoom: 1;
```

It helps with wrong positioning and disappeared elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution. Move the `toc` outside of the container with the scrolling div like this...

```
<body>
<div class="toc">
    <a data-rank="0" href="javascript:;">1</a>&nbsp;<a data-rank="1" href="javascript:;">2</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="sections">
    <div class="item" data-rank="0">
        <h1>1: Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-rank="1">
        <h2>2: Hello World</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

then amend the CSS so that the `toc` appears where you want it...

```
.toc {
    position: relative;
    top: 165px;
}
```